# react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I upgraded react native vrsion from 0.64.1 to latest. And when try to run

```
cd .\android\ && ./gradlew clean
```

I'm getting the following error,

```
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED
Caching disabled for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has failed previously.
The input changes require a full rebuild for incremental task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.
'compileJava' task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileKotlin' task (current target is 11) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
Using Kotlin/JVM incremental compilation
[KOTLIN] Kotlin compilation 'jdkHome' argument: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.14
i: found daemon on port 17773 (1316337 ms old), trying to connect
i: connected to the daemon
Options for KOTLIN DAEMON: IncrementalCompilationOptions(super=CompilationOptions(compilerMode=INCREMENTAL_COMPILER, targetPlatform=JVM, reportCategories=[0], reportSeverity=2, requestedCompilationResults=[0]kotlinScriptExtensions=[kt, kts, java]), areFileChangesKnown=false, modifiedFiles=null, deletedFiles=null, classpathChanges=org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.ClasspathChanges$NotAvailable$ClasspathSnapshotIsDisabled@34aad1e, workingDir=C:\Users\Chanduka\Desktop\hutch\src\smart-app\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\build\kotlin\compileKotlin, multiModuleICSettings=MultiModuleICSettings(buildHistoryFile=C:\Users\Chanduka\Desktop\hutch\src\smart-app\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\build\kotlin\compileKotlin\build-history.bin, useModuleDetection=false), usePreciseJavaTracking=trueoutputFiles=[C:\Users\Chanduka\Desktop\hutch\src\smart-app\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\build\classes\kotlin\main, C:\Users\Chanduka\Desktop\hutch\src\smart-app\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\build\kotlin\compileKotlin])
```

my java version is 11